# Custom Basic Authentication of a Web service

Tags: web-services, authentication, http-headers, basic-authentication

I'm having a small issue with implementing custom basic authentication for a asmx in .net 4.0.
I've created the HttpModule which would start the authentication process of the web service consumer runnig this code,

```
HttpApplication application = (source as HttpApplication);
HttpContext context = application.Context;
if ( VirtualPathUtility.GetFileName(context.Request.FilePath).Contains("svcEWS.asmx"))
{
    string username = "", password = "";

    string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
    {
        //Authenticate here
    }
}
```

However there is no authentication header present whenever this code is reached.
The consuming web app is simply calling,

```
EWS.svcEWS svcEWS = new EWS.svcEWS();
svcEWS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin", "example.com");
svcEWS.HelloWorld();
```

IIS is set to run with anonymous authentication to anonymous authentication to prevent it from catching any auth requests.

Is there something I'm missing to have the client pass the correct header to my module?

Comment: Microsoft has already supplied a method for customizing authentication of web services. It is called WCF! ASMX was not intended to be customized in this way. Don't waste your time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree, however in my particular case I am mimicking a preexisting webservice and have no control over the client that utilizes it.

Comment: Solved. Issue was I forgot to respond a 401 on failed auth requests to force the header.

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem, but customizing security in WCF would have been a lot cleaner than using an HttpModule and comparing to the file path.

Comment: You should add an answer showing how you changed your code to make it work, and then (once [SO] allows you), you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was forgetting to reject the first request with 401 code to force authentication. Doing so fixes the problem, as the invoker re sends the request with the auth header.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Could you please explain how you "reject the first request with 401 code to force authentication"?